# The console.log() prints 2 identical messages while creating react app

Tags: console, virtual-machine, create-react-app, console.log

There are two lines when using console.log() from my "react-app", how can I stop the second line from showing up?

Answer (score 2):

There could be a few reasons why. First and most likely is that your main app is wrapped in `<React.StrictMode>`.

If that's not true, then state may be updating, causing re-renders. Or if the `console.log` is in a `useEffect`, dependencies changing could cause this.

These blog posts have some good info on what may be happening and why:

- [My React components render twice and drive me crazy](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/)
- [React Components rendered twice — any way to fix this?](https://andreasheissenberger.medium.com/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using React strict mode or the React Chrome extension. Turn off the Chrome extension. When you command the strict mode, it will go off. If it's helpful, accept it as the answer.

[image]